# Is Microsoft IDisposable pattern actually correct?

Tags: c#, idisposable

I've stumbled across Microsoft's recommended way to implement the IDisposable pattern many times, it's even present in Visual Studio as an "Implement Interface" option in the lamp icon menu. It looks like this:

```cs
// Override only if 'Dispose(bool disposing)' has code to free unmanaged resources
~Foo() {
    // Do not change this code.
    Dispose(calledByFinalizer: true);
}
```

```cs
public void Dispose() {
    // Do not change this code. 
    Dispose(calledByFinalizer: false);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

```cs
// Put cleanup code here
protected virtual void Dispose(bool calledByFinalizer) {
    if (_disposed) return;

    if (!calledByFinalizer) { /* dispose managed objects */ }

    /* free unmanaged resources and set large fields to null */

    _disposed = true;
}
```

I refactored the suggested code a bit (because Dispose(bool disposing) can break someone's brain, and nested if's can break someone's eyes).

But I still have some questions on my mind:

1. It is assumed that the method will be called once. Then why is `_disposed = true` placed at the end of the method and not at the beginning? If `IDisposable.Dispose()` is called from different threads, then they can all bypass the `if (_disposed) return;` check and actually execute the method body twice. Why not do it like this:

```cs
    if (_disposed) return;
    else _disposed = true;
```

2. Why is `protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)` flagged as `virtual`? Any derived class does not have access to the `_disposed` field and can easily break its behavior. We can only mark as `virtual` the optional part where the derived class can do anything without calling `base.Dispose()`:

```cs
~Foo() => FreeUnmanagedResources();

public void Dispose() {
    if (_disposed) return;
    else _disposed = true;

    DisposeManagedObjects();
    FreeUnmanagedResources();

    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void DisposeManagedObjects() { }
protected virtual void FreeUnmanagedResources() { }
```

Comment: At first I thought the question should be simple to ask, but your last example *does* seem better to me... Implementations shouldn't reimplement the check if the object has been already disposed.

Comment: There is an interesting consequence to your implementation.  All managed objects at all levels will be disposed before all unmanaged resources.  Whereas in the standard pattern, it is on a per class basis, i.e. the derived class disposes of all its resources before passing to `base.Dispose(disposing)`.  I'm not sure whether this would matter or not.

Comment: A fundamental principle of the Dispose() method is that it is safe to call multiple times.  If the body of your method is _not_ safe to call multiple times, you would need to move setting `_disposed` earlier, as in your example.  However, commonly, you are unsubscribing events or calling Dispose on other disposables, so it wouldn't matter when you set `_disposed` except as an optimisation I guess.

Comment: `Dispose` is not meant to be thread-safe, it is only safe to call multiple times on a single thread. `if (_disposed) return; else _disposed = true;` is not thread-safe either and is subject to concurrency/race issues, you would need `Interlocked.CompareExchange`

Comment: ```DisposeManagedObjects()``` and ```FreeUnmanagedResources()``` is not really my idea, i just replaced the comments with these functions.

Comment: The best practice implementation is so universally accepted that it might even be off-topic for SO

Comment: We can't even say that this practice is the best. Satisfactory - yes, the best - no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pattern is correct, but assumes the worst case scenario, where you must also implement a finalizer. That is, if you need a finalizer you must also follow the entire pattern. However...

**It's RARE to need a finalizer at all.**

You only need a finalizer if you are creating the *original managed wrapper* for a brand new kind of unmanaged resource.

For example, let's say you create a brand new, never before seen database system. You want to provide a .Net ADO provider for this new kind of database, including the connections (it will inherit from DbConnection). The underlying network operations here will be an unmanaged resource, and there isn't already a finalizer to release them anywhere in your inhertitance tree. Therefore, you must implement your own finalizer.

On the other hand, if you are creating a wrapper object for your application to manage connections to an existing database type — just repacking (wrapping or inheriting) an existing SqlConnection, OleDbConnection, MySqlConnection, etc — then you should still implement IDisposable, but there is *already a finalizer provided* for the unmanaged resource and you *don't need to write another.*

And it turns out, when you don't have a finalizer you can safely remove a lot of the code from the documented IDisposable pattern.

From Microsoft's perspective, it's better to encourage people to add a few extra harmless lines of code rather then let them miss something potentially important.

Comment: I would also suggest that sealing such a class to prevent the creation of sub classes would be preferable to implementing `IDisposable` this way.

Comment: This is a very relevant note, but Microsoft is literally saying: I've already prepared a bit of copy-paste for you. I saw this code in Schildt's book and it hasn't changed at all, although there are obviously a couple of places where it's ugly.

Comment: Disposing can be ugly, we have no place being in there if we are going to judge the appearance of the code during the process of what is essentially _taking our object to the toilet and wiping it's bum_. It is no surprise to find this pattern in Schildt's C# book as this has always been a fundamental part of the lifecycle of an object instance in c#.

Comment: It will be ugly if you make it ugly. Big ball of mud will always be ugly. Regarding Schildt, many code samples from his book could make Uncle Bob angry. The pattern he proposed is not the only correct option, and specifically my implementation does not change it, but only corrects some parts.

Answer (score 1):

The guidance is correct, is accepted best practice and is fully documented here: [Implement a Dispose method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose)

Rule Number 1, DO NOT refactor the dispose pattern, it has explicit comments detailing where to perform each of the common operations and the finalizer is commented out by default (or should be) and should only be implemented if you have *unmanaged* resources to release. Feel free to remove the elements and comments that you don't need, but it helps make your code more accessible if you stick to the pattern that we all know and expect.

Visual Studio will give you suggestions for implementing the *Dispose pattern* as shown in this screenshot:
[image: implementing dispose pattern]

The best practice for this pattern is this, with the exception that I personally prefer to wrap this in a region block:

```
public class T : IDisposable
{
    #region IDisposable

    private bool disposedValue;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects)
            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override finalizer
            // TODO: set large fields to null
            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    // // TODO: override finalizer only if 'Dispose(bool disposing)' has code to free unmanaged resources
    // ~T()
    // {
    //     // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
    //     Dispose(disposing: false);
    // }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    #endregion IDisposable
}
```

> It is assumed that the method will be called once.

Yes we all make this assumption, but due to programmer discretion, threading and general bad design patterns, we all assume that some *nufty* will break our rules. Often it is an aggressive form of direct calling dispose in a UI that fires on close, but it happens in many other scenarios too. So the pattern provided is strongly advised to cater for the scenarios where dispose IS called multiple times.

> Why is protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) flagged as virtual? Any derived class does not have access to the _disposed field...

So the reason this method exists AND is virtual is specifically because the inheriting class does not have access to the `_disposed` field, the overriding implementation *should* call the base implementation:

```
base.Dispose(disposing):
```

If they don't then they will break the intended functionality as you say, but that is their perrogative, there are valid cases where we do specifically want to change the implementation, that is why we override.

As a UI control author this pattern is very useful and is a good level of encapsulation. In cases like yours most will end up overriding both `DisposeManagedObjects` and `FreeUnmanagedResources`. By separating these concerns you make it too hard to do any other C# Kung Fu that we might also want to do.

---

Your implementation is not bad, and in your use case arguably safer, but it is uniquely yours and does make some advanced tasks harder to implement or maintain because now the disposal code is split across 2 methods.

By using *standard* patterns, other developers and development tools are more likely to intrinsically understand and interact with your classes. This pattern has been developed over a number of years and is an aggregate of how we all used to do things in our own quirky ways.

The dispose pattern *is* hard to understand and until you need to override it, it is hard to see the value in this implementation. But when it goes wrong it is incredibly hard to debug, because it is often the last place we look (we always assume that it works) but it is also hard to track outside of a `using(){}` block.

Use the standards, those who inherit your code or run maintenance on it later will thank you.

---

Comment: I'm just not sure that all developers really understand how this pattern works (I am one of them), because it is always unchanged literally like copy-paste. That's why I inverted ```bool disposing``` to ```bool calledByFinalizer```.
Does anyone really prefer ```bool disposing```?

Comment: Many people misinterpreting the reasons behind this implementation is precisely why you should generally stick as close to it as you can. Certainly remove the elements that you do not need, but stick to the structure of the pattern to avoid common mistakes. Im not sure inverting is any more helpful, `calledByFinalizer` now introduces a new concept that new dev won't even be aware of. It is entirely subjective to the developer and their experience which way around is more understandable, its just helpful if we are all on the same page. IMO the `disposing` name makes more sense to me.

Comment: Not only is this pattern usually and expected to be _copy'n'pasted_ in, we should all be using the VS code suggestion to autocomplete the IDisposable pattern, no copy and paste at all, its a reusable code snippet. When `IDisposable` is implemented _incorrectly_ it can easily lead to memory leaks and other performance issues, so this is one case you want to pre-emptively get right, debugging the dispose/finalizer pattern is highly problematic.

Comment: And what does a new (any) dev think when he calls Dispose but disposing is false? It sounds like a meme and it's just bad naming that everyone copies when they don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Yes, there is literally the same snippet in Visual Studio. Maybe it's just a feature of Roslyn. But this fragment is a copypasta from Schildt's book (or something more ancient).

Comment: That's where we don't agree, I think the naming makes perfect sense, sometimes I'll call `Dispose(false);` deliberately in code to pre-emptively clean up un-managed resources while the object is still being used in the managed lifetime. (so it's like a soft dispose, without actually disposing) Classes that have image processing will see this a fair bit, to use `calledByFinalizer` wouldn't make sense at all in that scenario.

Comment: In general, a boolean flag is a code smell. If the behavior of a function changes completely from a flag alone, it clearly indicates that it does more than one thing.

Comment: The selector argument "code smell" is itself subjective. At some point we need to find a balance between individual methods for every possible nuance of our logic and what is practical and documentable. Only highly specific logic would be calling the protected implementation of `Dispose(bool disposing)`. Unsuspecting devs would try to override `Dispose()` and find the protected variant instead. In this case the discoverability of the code far outweighs the functional purist view against selector arguments. Also keep in mind that both methods will need to be maintained and called together.

Comment: It is common practice to avoid boolean flags. You can separate the release of managed and unmanaged resources. So why mix different scenarios in one method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242098/discussion-between-chris-schaller-and-fumanchez).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't assume that  `Dispose` is only going to get called once.  In best practice, yes.  In the worst practice, not at all.  Every situation cannot conveniently use a `using` statement.  So rather than risk the code trying to clean up unmanaged resources twice -- which could go really bad, depending on the type of resource -- there's a flag added that prevents it.  This takes a burden off the calling code as far as remembering if `dispose` has already been called.
2. `Dispose` has to be declared as virtual to support any separate cleanup that **might** need to occur if subclasses are created that instantiate any unmanaged resources that are *distinctly different* than those used in the base class.  `Dispose` in the subclass should call `base.Dispose();` before or after it cleans up its own mess.

Comment: 1. In the normal case, we WANT the method to be executed only once, and calling Dispose again on resources may cause them to work incorrectly rather than fix something.
2. This does not contradict my implementation, that's why I separated the cleanup methods and made them virtual, and not the entire Dispose method.

Comment: You're proceeding as you are now because you're the only consumer of your code.  But think a bit more universally.  If you are writing a library that you share with others (and Microsoft has many, many, many of these), you can't assume how they're going to code against any class in your library that implements IDisposable.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer my question. My implementation does not change the behavior, I just tried to make it more strict and predictable.

1. I did not remove the ```_disposed``` flag, the only difference is that I put it at the beginning of the method to prevent re-disposing.

2. First, the base class releases its resources, and then the derived one - thus, the derived class cannot release the resources of the base class.

So, the details change, but not the essence.